# How can I replacing empty ldtext column from longdescription table in maximo using sql

Tags: sql, db2, maximo

Symptom,Cause,Resolution are not filled up, so it empty, 
I want to replace the  fetched ldtext columns from long description table with some text.
I want show null columns with some text in a report.

Thank you

To replace null values in column use `COALESCE()` function . For DB2 specific solution use `IFNULL()` function.

```
SELECT COALESCE(columnName,'Some Text')
```

OR

```
SELECT IFNULL(columnName,'Some Text'

SELECT b.ticketid,(SELECT COALESCE(CAST(SYMPTOM.LDTEXT AS VARCHAR(1000),'text') 
                   FROM MAXIMO.LONGDESCRIPTION SYMPTOM  
                   WHERE SYMPTOM.LDOWNERCOL = 'PROBLEMCODE' 
                         AND SYMPTOM.LDOWNERTABLE = 'TICKET' 
                         AND SYMPTOM.LDKEY = B.TICKETUID) AS "symptom" 
FROM incident b
```

from the above query it doesn't work

```
SELECT b.ticketid, COALESCE(SELECT CAST(SYMPTOM.LDTEXT AS VARCHAR(1000)) 
                            FROM MAXIMO.LONGDESCRIPTION SYMPTOM  
                            WHERE SYMPTOM.LDOWNERCOL = 'PROBLEMCODE' 
                                  AND SYMPTOM.LDOWNERTABLE = 'TICKET' 
                                  AND SYMPTOM.LDKEY = B.TICKETUID), 'some text') AS "symptom"
FROM incident b
```

It work as above

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't a valid complaint; be specific, _what_ didn't work.  What were you expecting.  In the case of the first query, you're still anticipating rows in `MAXIMO.LONGDESCRIPTION`, just not necessarily values in column `LDTEXT`.  In the second, the query works in the absence of rows.  It looks like you want a `LEFT JOIN`, which will probably perform better.  Oh, avoid quotations on column names (and other identifiers) - it makes them behave strangely.

Comment: Thanks Muse for your comments,

Answer (score 0):

To replace null values in column use `COALESCE()` function . For DB2 specific solution use `IFNULL()` function.

```
SELECT COALESCE(columnName,'Some Text')
```

OR

```
SELECT IFNULL(columnName,'Some Text')
```

Comment: IFNULL only works on db2 for z/OS. Does not work on LUW

Comment: `COALESE(..)` is the SQL Standard function anyways, can you give a reason why you're advocating a non-standard function?

Comment: Thanks Muse for your comments, I need to clear confusion here, need to show the symptom,cause and resolution in the report from incident management, where ever these are null columns or without data i need to place some text the above three columns replacing blank.